# how to create a slide layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

in my application I would create a new layout, like the standard Android where you see the clock, battery, etc. That Is, it opens with the slide of the finger on the screen. How do I proceed?

Comment: are you talking about the Notification panel?

Comment: yes i want to insert a notification panel in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a ViewPager

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
android:background="#234567"/>
```

See:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

You can also do a ViewPager solution as Fragments.  This is the way to go.